# Does Azure Active Directory authenticate Virtual and Physical server access?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Just like Active Directory installed in Windows Servers, does Azure Active Directory does the same thing? Note: Please feel free to edit my question if its not relevant.

Comment: If I understand properly, Azure AD Domain Service can do this. See more details in this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-overview

Comment: Hi Wayne, I've read the article and it says there that Azure AD Domain Service can do that as Azure AD Connect syncs the on-premise Active Directory to the Azure Cloud. Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you read this document carefully? Azure AD Domain Services integrates with your existing Azure AD tenant, thus making it possible for users to log in using their corporate credentials.  So, it supply an Identity Authentication with Azure AD.